# Selecting columns in Postgres that aren't in GROUP BY?

Tags: sql, postgresql, greatest-n-per-group

So I've been working in sqlite3 where the following command works:

```
select origin_city, dest_city, actual_time 
FROM flights 
GROUP BY origin_city 
ORDER BY actual_time desc;
```

but when trying to do this in psql, it doesn't like that dest_city and actual_time are not in the GROUP BY clause. I am trying to select the longest flight from each origin location and displaying the origin, destination, and flight time.  How can I resolve this?

Comment: By either adding them in the group by or using aggregate function such as max on them

Comment: What are you trying to do? The statement makes no sense.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name selecting the longest flight from each origin location and displaying the origin, destination, and flight time

Answer (score 0):

Based on your updated question, you can use `row_number` window function to mark the longest flight with value 1 and so on and then, filter for top row:

```
select origin_city, dest_city, actual_time
from (
  select
    t.*,
    row_number() over (partition by origin_city order by actual_time desc) rn
  from flights t
) t where rn = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `ROW_NUMBER()` function for this in a cte or subquery:

```
WITH cte as (SELECT *
                    ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY origin_city ORDER BY actual_time DESC) RN 
              FROM flights
             )
SELECT origin_city, dest_city, actual_time 
FROM cte
WHERE RN = 1
ORDER BY actual_time DESC;
```

The `ROW_NUMBER()` function assigns a number to each row. `PARTITION BY` is optional, but used to start the numbering over for each value in that group,  ie: if you `PARTITION BY origin_city`  then for each unique `origin_city` value the numbering would start over at 1.  `ORDER BY` of course is used to define how the counting should go, and is required in the `ROW_NUMBER()` function.

Many databases do not allow you to have a non-aggregate field in the `SELECT` list that's not also in the `GROUP BY` clause when a `GROUP BY` clause is present, MySQL and SQLite do allow this, but it can return undesired results in certain situations.

Comment: An example of your original query returning undesired results is shown here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/fe872/1/0  Notice how it returns the lowest value for `col3` even though it's ordering by that field descending, it is not reliable.

Answer (score 0):

Why now creating a temporary table holding maximum actual_time for each origin_city?

```
SELECT temp.origin_city, flights.dest_city, temp.actual_time 
FROM (
  SELECT origin_city, MAX(actual_time) actual_time 
  FROM flights 
  GROUP BY origin_city 
) temp
JOIN flights using (origin_city, actual_time)
ORDER BY temp.actual_time DESC
```